# get NACE codes with regex

Tags: python, regex

I want to extract the [NACE codes](http://ec.europa.eu/competition/mergers/cases/index/nace_all.html) from a webpage with a Regex. I got this:

```
(?P<first>[A-U])(?P<second>\d{1,2})(?P<delimiter>[- /.])(?P<third>\d{1,2})(?P<secdelimiter>[- /.])(?P<forth>\d{1,2})
```

This will get me NACE codes like A1.1.1, but not A1.1 or A1. How can I make the expression take these as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the additional capturing groups optional using `?`, for example:

```
(?P<n1>\w\d{1,2})(?P<d1>[- /.])?(?P<n2>\d{1,2})?(?P<d2>[- /.])?(?P<n3>\d{1,2})?
                             # ^ means "zero or one times"
```

See demo on [regex101](http://regex101.com/r/qU6bA1).